# calculate time difference by group using data.table get the units messed up

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

The objective is to calculate the time between events grouped by some id. Here is an example:

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dt <- data.table(id = c(1,1:3), 
                 start = c("2015-01-01 12:00:00", "2015-12-01 12:00:00", "2019-01-01 12:00:00", NA),
                 end = c("2016-01-01 12:00:01", "2016-01-01 12:00:01", "2019-01-01 12:00:01", "2019-01-01 12:00:02"))

dt[, start := ymd_hms(start)]
dt[, end := ymd_hms(end)]

dt[, time_diff_1 := min(end) - max(start), by = .(id)]
dt[, time_diff_2 := end - start]
```

which results in:

```r
   id               start                 end   time_diff_1   time_diff_2
1:  1 2015-01-01 12:00:00 2016-01-01 12:00:01 31.00001 secs 31536001 secs
2:  1 2015-12-01 12:00:00 2016-01-01 12:00:01 31.00001 secs  2678401 secs
3:  2 2019-01-01 12:00:00 2019-01-01 12:00:01  1.00000 secs        1 secs
4:  3                <NA> 2019-01-01 12:00:02       NA secs       NA secs
```

Both columns `time_diff_1` and `time_diff_2` display the time difference in seconds. However the `time_diff_1` which resulted from the grouped calculation mixed up the units. The result for `id == 1` is 31 days and one second. It seems as if the units were choosen automatically by group and then gotten overwritten.

Any hints on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When using the `difftime()` function the units can be set explicitly, e.g.

```r
dt[, time_diff_3 := difftime(min(end), max(start), units = "secs"), by = .(id)]
```

resulting in

```r
   id               start                 end   time_diff_1   time_diff_2  time_diff_3
1:  1 2015-01-01 12:00:00 2016-01-01 12:00:01 31.00001 secs 31536001 secs 2678401 secs
2:  1 2015-12-01 12:00:00 2016-01-01 12:00:01 31.00001 secs  2678401 secs 2678401 secs
3:  2 2019-01-01 12:00:00 2019-01-01 12:00:01  1.00000 secs        1 secs       1 secs
4:  3                <NA> 2019-01-01 12:00:02       NA secs       NA secs      NA secs
```

with the expected result found in column `time_diff_3`.

However, there might be still room for improvement regarding how `data.table` **silently** overwrites the units after the grouped calculation. The results caused some head scratching before I figured out the units got messed up.